# Alpha mask for an image in govips

Tags: go, image-processing, vips

In [govips](https://github.com/davidbyttow/govips), how to create an alpha mask - basically an image having black pixels which are transparent and white for the ones which have 0 transparency - so creating an image from the alpha channel of the given image?